# What's the difference between 'Pick<A & B, keyof A | keyof B> ' and 'A & B' in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, extends

```js
type A = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};
type B = {
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
};
```

I have test the extends relationship, It shows true:

```
type Expected1 = Pick<A & B, keyof A | keyof B> extends A & B ? true : false; // true
type Expected2 = A & B extends Pick<A & B, keyof A | keyof B> ? true : false; // true
```

But got falsy with `Equal` type:

```js
type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false

type Expected3 = Equal<A & B, Pick<A & B, keyof A | keyof B>> // false
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I've typically seen `Equal` written as the far simpler `type Equal<X, Y> = X extends Y ? Y extends X ? true : false : false` which does return `true` here. https://tsplay.dev/wQKQjm Not 100% sure why that equality check fails though.

Comment: Attach a [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961864/how-does-the-equals-work-in-typescript/68963796#68963796)  about this `Equal` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Equal function devised by [mattmccutchen](https://github.com/mattmccutchen) did not pass test H in [this Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issue-358956816)

```
type A = number == string;// false
type B = 1 == 1;// true
type C = any == 1;// false
type D = 1 | 2 == 1;// false
type E = Head<[1,2,3]> == 1;// true(see:#24897)
type F = any == never;// false
type G = [any] == [number];// false
type H = {x:1}&{y:2} == {x:1,y:2}// true
```

> Here's a solution that makes creative use of the assignability rule for conditional types, which requires that the types after extends be "identical" as that is defined by the checker:
>
> export type Equals<X, Y> =
> (() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
> (() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;
>
> This passes all the tests from the initial description that I was able to run except H, which fails because the definition of "identical" doesn't allow an intersection type to be identical to an object type with the same properties. (I wasn't able to run test E because I don't have the definition of Head.)

Your example falls into the case of H perfectly.

Here is the original github comment link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650

Comment: Thx a lot, I followed the link you provided and solved my doubts.

Comment: done! This is my first time asking a question :)